Prevent mod_auth_openidc / Google OAuth from prompting user selection
I am using mod_auth_openidc on Apache 2.4 and for my users that are connected to multiple accounts, they get prompted for user selection every time a new session is initiated (ie: the previous session has expired)
This seems to be linked to the prompt parameter being passed by default Google OAuth url params
The relevant config is like so :
OIDCScope "openid email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
OIDCRemoteUserClaim email
OIDCCacheType shm

OIDCSessionInactivityTimeout 14400
OIDCInfoHook iat access_token_expires id_token
OIDCAuthRequestParams hd=domain.com
OIDCOAuthTokenIntrospectionInterval 3600
OIDCXForwardedHeaders X-Forwarded-Proto X-Forwarded-Host

OIDCOAuthIntrospectionTokenParamName access_token
OIDCPassIDTokenAs claims serialized
# FOR Testing purposes
OIDCInfoHook iat access_token access_token_expires id_token id_token_hint userinfo refresh_token exp timeout remote_user session

